# Problems sending modals directly to a different channel using Discord.py 2.0

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm having problems with the modal component in my bot, I want to make a feedback feature where members can send a text to a private channel for mods only, but when it doesn't directly respond to the user's message in the same channel (using await interaction.respond.send_message)  it displays as "Interaction failed" even though the message was correctly sent to the mod channel (using bot.get_channel and channel.send). My current solution is to use delete_original_message after sending the response but I wanted a more elegant solution.

Here's the code:

```
async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        feedback_form = discord.Embed(
            title=None,
            description= f"{self.feedback}\n\n", 
            color=3092790)
        feedback_form.set_author(name = interaction.user, icon=interaction.user.avatar)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=feedback_form)
        await interaction.delete_original_message()


        channel = bot.get_channel(965032417901576202)
        await channel.send(embed=feedback_form)
```

Comment: To not get an "Interaction failed" you have to respond to the interaction unfortunately. I would recommend sending an ephermeral message confirming the submission or something along those lines, or maybe using `interaction.response.defer()` in some way?

Comment: Yeah, interaction.response.defer() worked perfectly! I also tried sending a confirmation and it was also not a bad idea.  Thank you for both great suggestions!